# Navision RDLC display rich text

Tags: c#, rdlc, navision

is there any possibility to display rich text in a RDLC Report?

My only idea is to convert rich text to an jpg i found an exmaple on MSDN how to do that using c#.(see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ef314de-8cd7-4ff6-83b5-a57ce011b36a/convert-richtextbox-text-to-jpeg?forum=csharpgeneral) But I think that's to much Overhead.

But there must be a better way to Display formated text in Report.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
1. Double click inside a cell [ Textbox],ryt click the same and select
    create a place holder . 

2.  Value Expression Would be ="<i>I am<i> <b>"& Fields!Name.Value &
    "</b>" 

3.  Mark up type -- select HTML-Interpret HTML tags as Styles .
```